# How to calculate number of characters that will render in a ui element before render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

How to calculate number of characters that will render in a ui element before render (considering some logic to be implemented based on it, one option can be to use monospace and know the width of the element). Any other better approach ?

Comment: What do you mean number of characters? What is it needed for? Can't you just do string.length?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: There is an onlayout prop for View/Text/... to measure the size it occupied

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your logic into `componentDidMount` method